# Como creo tantas variables como necesite dentro de un ciclo en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Recién estoy aprendiendo Javascript y me encontraba realizando un ejercicio sobre objetos.. La idea es crear Objetos y ordenarlos dentro de un array. Quise mejorarlo, haciendo que el usuario ingrese tantos como él quiera y lo conseguí.. el problema viene cuando quiero buscar dentro del array algún objeto en específico:

```
   function karro(marca,modelo,annio){
        this.marca=marca;
        this.modelo=modelo
        this.annio=annio;
    }
    var arreglo=[];;
    var answer="si"
    while(answer=="si"){
        var x=prompt("Marca?");
        var y=prompt("Modelo?");
        var z=prompt("annio?")
        z=Number(z)

    arreglo.push(new karro(x,y,z))
    answer=prompt("Ingresaras otro modelo mi rey?")
}
console.log(arreglo);
```

Quisiera que el nuevo elemento no se llame Karro siempre, sino como el usuario elija. Juan, Pedro.. para poder buscar el auto de juan o de pedro.. No se como hacer que la variable no se llame igual en cada vez que el ciclo se repite!
De antemano muchas gracias al que se tome el tiempo!

Comment: creo que lo estás enfocando mal, deberías tener una **clase** `karro`, y de ahí, **instanciar** tantos objetos como quieras.

Comment: Los objetos que guardas en el arreglo no tienen nombre. Si vas a buscar debes hacerlo según las propiedades internas del objeto (marca, modelo annio).

Comment: O lo otro que puedes hacer es asignar un dueño a cada carro, algo como `this.owner="juan"` y luego si quieres buscar el carro de juan, buscas el objeto que tenga `owner==="juan"`